# Tramp mode - Copying files

Tags: dired, tramp, files, ssh

when copying files in tramp mode via ssh with Dired I am not able to do anything else in Emacs. Emacs is just not usable till this process has finished.

Is there any way to use Emacs while it copies files in tramp mode via ssh with Dired? Or is this just impossible without using two emacs servers at once?

Answer (score 5):

You can use `dired-async-do-copy` from [emacs-async](https://github.com/jwiegley/emacs-async) to Run ‘dired-do-copy’ asynchronously.

Comment: 'dired-async-do-copy` is not a built-in command, you shoul mention the package that provides it

Comment: @matteol Thank your advice. I forgot about it.